# No mapea para la petición HTTP con URI [/nameapp/] en DispatcherServlet con nombre 'spring'

Tags: spring, maven, hibernate, wildfly

Las técnologias que uso son (spring 4, hibernate 4, tiles, maven, wildfly 10)

> [ WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/opciondefensa/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring']

InicioController.java :

```
@Controller
public class InicioController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
        String url="";
        url = "home";
        mav.setViewName(url);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

web.xml :

```
  <display-name>OpcionDefensa</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml.

```
<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<!--     <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
<!--     <context:annotation-config /> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.opciondefensa.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.opciondefensa.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.opciondefensa.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.opciondefensa.util" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="cl.opciondefensa.entity" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />

    <!-- Tiles configuration -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Getting Database properties -->
<!--     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" /> -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> -->
<!--        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="user" value="${database.username}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" /> -->
<!--         <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="cl.opciondefensa.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">${hibernate.connection.characterEncoding}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">${hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries}</prop>     
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics">${hibernate.cache.generate_statistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml :

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.1</tiles.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>0.9.26</logback.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1208</postgresql.version>
        <joda.version>2.2</joda.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>        
        </dependency>
<!-- commons logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- Amazon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.75</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  postgres  Connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>          
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>                        
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>${hibernate.version}</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->

    <!-- optional -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>opciondefensa</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

tiles-definitions.xml :

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultLayout" template="/WEB-INF/Layout/home/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" expression="${titulo_tiles}" />
        <put-attribute name="description" expression="${descripcion_tiles}" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/Layout/home/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="left" value="/WEB-INF/Layout/home/left.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="right" value="/WEB-INF/Layout/home/right.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/Layout/home/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

<!--    SITIO PUBLICO -->
    <definition name="home" extends="defaultLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/inicio/home.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

jboss-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: @Paul Vargas Gracias Profesor por la edición, algún aporte a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo InicioController, en la linea:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

debe poner `opciondefensa`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/opciondefensa", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: no sucedio nada cambiando el value, haciendo debug no me esta mostrando los breakpoint.. gracias igual por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

La configuración de `<context-root>/</context-root>` del archivo **jboss-web.xml** está mal.

Te recomiendo añadir:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
       <warName>nombredespliegue</warName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<context-root>/nombredespliegue</context-root>
```