# Java - El servicio web no reconoce el datasource almacenado en JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

Trabajo con los frameworks Spring y Hibernate para configurar la persistencia de la base de datos. En mi clase DAO, tengo la siguiente variable:

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Para configurar este `sessionFactory`, tengo el siguiente archivo de configuración:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup
        id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="java:jboss/NaughtClockDS"
        lookup-on-startup="true"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>entity.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

En la interfaz de ***JBoss EAP 7.2***, tengo configurado lo siguiente:

**JDBC Driver postgresql:**
[image: JDBC Driver postgresql]

**Web-Service Datasource:**
[image: Web Service Datasource]

Sin embargo, no está reconociendo la URL colocada en Datasource, porque cuando lo imprimo, me devuelve `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/`. Lo que me da a entender que no está reconociendo el datasource configurado en JBoss.

¿Hay algo más que debo configurar?

**Actualización**

Por el momento, sólo estoy probando con una tabla. Y también con una clase base que será la superclase de las tablas (luego, agregaré datos de auditoría)

Clase base: `BaseEntity.java`

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "retired")
    protected Boolean retired;

    public BaseEntity() {
        this.retired = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void retire() {
        this.retired = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

Clase `User.java`

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "uspgncl01")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Unique ID.
     */
    @Column(name = "token")
    protected String token;

    /**
     * User name.
     */
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    /**
     * User email.
     */
    @Column(name = "email")
    protected String email;

    /**
     * User photo URI.
     */
    @Column(name = "photo_uri")
    protected String photoUri;

    /**
     * Indicator whether the user is verified.
     */
    @Column(name = "verified")
    protected Boolean verified;

    public User() {}

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhotoUri() {
        return photoUri;
    }

    public void setPhotoUri(String photoUri) {
        this.photoUri = photoUri;
    }

    public Boolean getVerified() {
        return verified;
    }

    public void setVerified(Boolean verified) {
        this.verified = verified;
    }

}
```

**Conexión de datasource**
[image: Conexión de datasource]

**Seguridad**
[image: Seguridad de datasource]

Comment: Te faltan varias configuraciones, como la del usuario y contraseña para conectar , la tabla etc...

Comment: Por que no intentas ponerle los datos que faltan basándote en la configuración de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16865/no-mapea-para-la-petici%c3%b3n-http-con-uri-nameapp-en-dispatcherservlet-con-nomb